# Internet Explorer 11 developer tools mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, internet-explorer-11

I'm using Internet Explorer 11 and when I click F12 I get the developer tools window, which contains in particular a combobox to select the Internet Explorer version display style at the top right. (See picture below)

[image]

The problem is that the option IE11 is not available in the dropdown list, so I would like to know if there is a way to activate it.

**EDIT**: The exact version of IE I'm using is 11.0.9600.18376

Comment: this is the document mode. do you have other modes available on the "Emulation" tab? does it change with the doctype headers of the currently open website? especially the "default 5" seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'm not directly answering your question my IE11 (11.212.10586) has this menu item, maybe its a version thing....

[image]